# Select a Range of Elements from a List in Terraform

Tags: terraform

Is there a way to select a range of elements from a list in Terraform?

For example - if we have:

```
[a, bb, ccc, dddd, eeeee]
```

How can the first 3 elements be selected?

```
a, bb, ccc
```

And then the 4th and 5th elements?

```
dddd, eeeee
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Subsets of lists as you are looking for are often referred to as slices. Terraform has a built-in function for this, called `slice`, which is availble since version 0.8.8. You are looking for

```
slice(<put_reference_to_list_here, 0, 3)
slice(<put_reference_to_list_here, 3, 5)
```

From the documentation:

> slice(list, from, to) - Returns the portion of list between from (inclusive) and to (exclusive).

Most notably `slice` is picky about the `to` parameter, which may must be less or equal to the lists length, otherwise TF will complain. 
These `fromIndex,toIndex` interfaces are not intuitive for me, so I started to keep code snippets around for every language I (have to) use. This is my helper for Terraform:

```
variable "mylist" { default = [ 101, 102, 103, 104, 105 ] }

locals{
    everything = "${slice(var.mylist, 0                   , length(var.mylist)  )}"
    butlast    = "${slice(var.mylist, 0                   , length(var.mylist)-1)}"
    thelast    = "${slice(var.mylist, length(var.mylist)-1, length(var.mylist)  )}"
  }


data "null_data_source" "slices" {
  inputs {
    everything = "${join(",",local.everything)}"
    butlast    = "${join(",",local.butlast)}"
    thelast    = "${join(",",local.thelast)}"
  }
}

output "slices" {
  value = "${data.null_data_source.slices.outputs}"
}
```

To spare you the effort of `terraform init; terraform refresh`:

```
data.null_data_source.slices: Refreshing state...

Outputs:

slices = {
  butlast = 101,102,103,104
  everything = 101,102,103,104,105
  thelast = 105
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [slice function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#slice-list-from-to-).  That page describes the full expression language available to you.

Depending on where that list comes from, you might find it more convenient to split it up at its source.  For instance, instead of declaring 5 `aws_instance` resources then trying to slice their output this way, have two separate `aws_instance` declarations of 3 and 2 instances respectively, and just deal with the entire list of outputs.

Comment: Ah, that one slipped my sight - thank you, David! I believe it will be useful if every TF built-in function has a separate webpage for it and a couple of examples for various use cases - I'm going to propose that to the TF's Team.

Comment: And by the way - I'm trying to finish code which should be able to create multiple hosted zones, create multiple AWS ACM certs and validate automatically them through DNS Validation. And I'm trying to have as DRY as possible code - without declaring anything twice, etc. The function above was needed for slicing the "validation_record_fqdns" in the final step of the validation.